# Calculate the number of possible combinations of permutations between n sets without repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose I have 60 objectes numbered from 1 to 60. This is the input.

I need to create sets for these 60 objects, e.g: 6 sets of 10, 4 sets of 15, 3 sets of 20 or 2 sets of 30.

Suppose I have this "combo" of 3 sets with 20 numbers each:

`set a = {01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
set b = {21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40}
set c = {41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60}`

Now I have to permute the numbers between these 3 sets without repetition.

combo2 =

`set a = {01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
set b = {21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,41}
set c = {40,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60}`

combo3=

`set a = {01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
set b = {21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,42}
set c = {40,41,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60}`

comboN = etc...

How do I calculate the number of possible combos of 3 sets x 20 numbers ?

All help is appreciated to improve this question.

EDIT: the order of the numbers doesn't matter. If distinct numbers are distributed in 3 sets of 20, there is a unique / distinguishable "combo".

Comment: I provided an answer for which the three sets are not distinct, i.e. the order of the sets does not matter. If this assumption is false, the answers by Jorge and Frpzzd are more appropriate.

Comment: @JonePolvora OK, then jvdhooft and my Answer are correct, and you need to divide Jorge's and Frpzzd Answers by $3!=6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of all the possible ways you can line up all $60$ objects: there are $60!$ such 'line-ups'.  Now put the first $20$ into one set, the next $20$ into the next, and the last $20$ into a third. However, this $60!$ will overcount the number of ways we can partition the $60$ into 3 groups of $20$ in two ways:

First, the first 20 items in each line-up can be reordered in any of $20!$ ways, while still giving the same result for the three groups. Therefore, you need to divide that $60!$ by $20!$.  And of course the same holds for groups $2$ and $3$. So divide by another $20!$ and then another $20!$

Second, if the groups don't have a unique identity (i.e. if you don't separate the 60 into 3 distinguishable groups like 'Gryffindor', 'Ravenclaw', and 'Hufflepuff'), but if instead you are just looking to just partition the $60$ into any $3$ otherwise indistinguishable groups of twenty (and I think you are), then notice that the first twenty in the line-up can be swapped with the second twenty, and you would still have the same resulting groups. Since there are $3!$ to swap the three groups, while geting the same result every time, we need to divide our answer by $3!$.

In sum: There are

$$\frac{60!}{20!20!20!3!}$$

ways to partition $60$ objects into $3$ (otherwise indistinguishable) sets of $20$.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the order doesn't matter, so we don't have to reorder the numbers in each set. Thanks for your explanation and effort!

Comment: @JonePolvora You're welcome!  I figured an explanation would be more helpful than just the formula :)

Comment: is this correct ? =96.305.202.413.079.303.971.977.650

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: I'm a programmer developing a lottery app and I asked this question because I was not sure if I was doing something wrong. I'm trying to generate all possible combinations based on this question and now I see that is not possible with a common computer to produce this combinations. =/

Comment: @JonePolvora Yes, that number is far too big indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the "partitions" formula. This formula states that the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into groups of $g_1,g_2,...,g_k$ so that all items are placed in some group (that is, $g_1+g_2+...+g_k=n$) is
$$\frac{n!}{g_1!g_2!...g_k!}$$
So, given $60$ distinct objects, the number of ways to partition them into three sets of $20$ is
$$\frac{60!}{20!20!20!}\approx5.77*10^{26}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by the multinomial coefficient $\binom{60}{20,20,20}=\frac{60!}{20!\times 20! \times 20!}$.

In general if you have $nk$ elements and $k$ groups you want $\binom{nk}{\underbrace{n, \dots , n}_k}=\frac{nk!}{\underbrace{n!\times \dots \times n!}_k}$